# SafeWaitHandle vs SafeFileHandle c#

Tags: c#, .net, base-class-library

I'm reading .net framework source on:
https://referencesource.microsoft.com

I have found out that BCL contains two absolutely same classes: `SafeWaitHandle` & `SafeFileHandle`. Both of them have absolutely the same code!

From reference source (SafeFileHandle):

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
public sealed class SafeFileHandle: SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid {

    private SafeFileHandle() : base(true) 
    {
    }

    public SafeFileHandle(IntPtr preexistingHandle, bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle) {
        SetHandle(preexistingHandle);
    }

    [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
    [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
    override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
    {
        return Win32Native.CloseHandle(handle);
    }
}
```

From reference source (SafeWaitHandle):

```
[System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
    public sealed class SafeWaitHandle : SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid
    {
        // Called by P/Invoke marshaler
        private SafeWaitHandle() : base(true)
        {
        }

        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.WillNotCorruptState, Cer.MayFail)]
        public SafeWaitHandle(IntPtr existingHandle, bool ownsHandle) : base(ownsHandle)
        {
            SetHandle(existingHandle);
        }

        [System.Security.SecurityCritical]
        [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.Machine)]
        [ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine)]
        override protected bool ReleaseHandle()
        {
            return Win32Native.CloseHandle(handle);
        }
    }
```

I see that constructors have different names for `IntPtr` parameters and comment for SafeWaitHandle trying to tell something to me. But I can't understand because code is equal and to my understand these classes should provide the same behavior.

Does anybody know why microsoft guys created these equals classes? Why should I prefer one class to another one and in what cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is semantics. Most handles are similar - just a reference (often just a pointer) to some resource. However, it's useful to differentiate them. If you have some api which accepts `SafeFileHandle` - it will not accept `SafeWaitHandle` (or other type of handles that exist), which might prevent some subtle bugs. If it instead accepted some abstract `Handle` - then someone could pass any handle there, something not representing reference to a file. So different types of handles being represented by different classes (even with identical implementation) + C# type safety is beneficial to prevent passing handle of one type where handle of another type is expected.

Comment: there is a logic in your words and i think this is an answere to my question. But if it is so, why do they duplicate the code? why didn't they create base class for incapsulating all this logic and create two clasess like `class SafeWaitHandle : BaseSimpleHandle { }` and `class SafeFileHandle : BaseSimpleHandle { }` They are both in one namespace.

Comment: Well that I don't know, maybe code duplication is so small that they considered it's not worth it. Maybe they think those handles semantically do not belong to the same base class (other than `SafeHandleZeroOrMinusOneIsInvalid`).